# Trying to toggle background color with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to get a button to change the background color of an element by changing it's class.
I've combined js from a few different sources, but it's not working and I can't figure out why.

```js
 
 
 function myFunc() {
   var y = document.getElementById("bg-change1").getAttribute("class");
   if (y === "normal") {
     y = "active";
   } else {
     y = "normal";
   }
 }
```

```css
.normal {
  background-color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunc()">click here</button>
  <div id="bg-change1" class="normal">
    <p>Lorem ipsum and etc</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the value at the end, you are only getting the value which isn't enough. You are simply missing `document.getElementById("bg-change1").setAttribute("class",y);` at the end of the function.

```js
function myFunc() {
   var y = document.getElementById("bg-change1").getAttribute("class");
   if (y === "normal") {
     y = "active";
   } else {
     y = "normal";
   }
   document.getElementById("bg-change1").setAttribute("class",y);
 }
```

```css
.normal {
  background-color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunc()">click here</button>
  <div id="bg-change1" class="normal">
    <p>Lorem ipsum and etc</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it short format with pure JavaScript:

```
function myFunc() {
   var y = document.getElementById("bg-change1");
   y.classList.toggle("active")
}
```

But keep it mind the current css selector order need to must to give the '.active' class precedence over '.normal'.

Comment: maybe it's better to add a full code to show him ;)

Comment: Based his code nothing need to change if just follow my function that is enough to work perfectly.

Comment: i know, but it will simply make you answer more complete

Answer (score 1):

`getAttribute("class")` returns the content of the attribute at the moment you call it. Since that is a string there's no reference to the element. Reassigning `y` therefore doesn't do anything.

To actually change the attribute you can use `setAttribute("class", "active")`. But that's not a good solution because you can't have more than one class and the `normal` class is unnecessary.

Just apply the default styles using a different selector (`#bg-change1` for example) and override properties that you want to change in the `.active` selector. You can then switch between both "modes" using `document.getElementById("bg-change1").classList.toggle("active")`.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit of a runaround way to add and remove a class. I would suggest implementing the toggle class method, see below:

```js
 
 
 function myFunc() {
   var y = document.getElementById("bg-change1");
   y.classList.toggle("active");
 }
```

```css
.normal {
  background-color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button onclick="myFunc()">click here</button>
  <div id="bg-change1" class="normal">
    <p>Lorem ipsum and etc</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are retrieving class in y and changing class name but it doesnt set to element back.

instead you can use

```
function myFunc() {
  var y = document.getElementById("bg-change1").getAttribute("class");
  if (y === "normal") {
    document.getElementById("bg-change1").classList.remove('normal');
    document.getElementById("bg-change1").classList.add('active');
  } else {
    document.getElementById("bg-change1").classList.remove('active');
    document.getElementById("bg-change1").classList.add('normal');
  }
}
```

Comment: For shorter format you can use Hanif's answer with .toggle function

Answer (score -1):

You successfully get the attribute but you never change or set it. Do that with `document.getElementById("bg-change1").setAttribute("class", y);`

Example:

```js
function myFunc() {
  var y = document.getElementById("bg-change1").getAttribute("class");
  if (y === "normal") {
    y = "active";
  } else {
    y = "normal";
  }
  document.getElementById("bg-change1").setAttribute("class", y);
}
```

```css
.normal {
  background-color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunc()">click here</button>
<div id="bg-change1" class="normal">
  <p>Lorem ipsum and etc</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Anonymous coward downvoter care to comment? Please do us all a favor and grow a pair and explain what's wrong with this answer.